# How to put QgsCheckableComboBox() into standby

Tags: python, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqt5, combo-box

I'm trying `QgsCheckableComboBox()` in my simple python script in QGIS. How to pause code execution while a comboBox-window is open (like a dialog box)? In my example, I want to ensure that the `print()` function is executed only after the comboBox-window is closed. Then the `checkedItems` list will not be empty and will contain the selected lines ("Venus", "Earth", "Mars"). How can I achieve this?

```
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui
from qgis.core import *

planet_list = ["Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Pluto"]
items = QgsCheckableComboBox()
items.addItems(planet_list)
items.showNormal()

print('\n\n-----------CheckedItems: ', items.checkedItems())
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Have you tried any other approaches than the code posted? And can you clarify, the code currently executes, but the `print()` is not waiting for the combo box interaction?

Comment: No, I have not tried other approaches. Yes that's right, the print() is not waiting for the combo box interaction, but your code solved my problem!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add the combobox to a dialog window. After closing the dialog, `print` prints the selected items.

```py
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui
from qgis.core import *

planet_list = ["Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Pluto"]
items = QgsCheckableComboBox()
items.addItems(planet_list)

dlg = QDialog()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(items)
dlg.setLayout(layout)
dlg.exec_()

print('\n\n-----------CheckedItems: ', items.checkedItems())
```